# How can I create a language using set operation to prove a language is not regular?

Tags: regular-languages

My goal is to show, that a given language is not a regular one by using the Properties of Regular Languages.

The language is $  A \triangleq\left\{w \in \Sigma^{*} \mid |\left.w\right|_{b} \neq|w|_{c} \wedge|w|>0\right\}  $ with $  \Sigma \triangleq\{a, b, c\}  $

My idea is to use this clearly non regular language (which is given in the task, so I can/should use it) $  \left\{b^{n} c^{n} | n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}  $ to prove $A$ is also no regular language.

Could the following work?

$(A\cap L(b^*c^*)) \cdot \mathrm{L}(\boldsymbol{\epsilon}) = \left\{b^{n} c^{n} | n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are onto the right track. However, your notation is confusing me.

I would believe the following is what you are coming at.

$$\overline{(A\cap L(b^*c^*))} \cup \{\epsilon\} = \left\{b^{n} c^{n} \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$$
where $\overline S$ is the language of words not in $S$, a.k.a. the complement of $S$. Here are the facts that you will use.

- $b^*c^*$ is a regular expression.
- the intersection of two regular languages is regular.
- the complement of a regular language is regular.
- $\{\epsilon\}$ is a regular language.
- the union of two regular languages is regular.
- $\{b^{n} c^{n} \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is not regular.

I will leave the rest of reasoning to you.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer.

But there are two problems:
First, I should not use  the complement, because our proof did not mentioned it, so there is no proof for that.

Second, this here   $(A\cap L(b^*c^*)) $ should look like $L(b^*c^*) \ \{\epsilon\}$ right? So we just need to add the empty word, right? 

So is there a use for the complement in this case? I believe withe the complement the language is not right. But I'am just i my first year on university, so I'm maybe wrong.

Comment: I mean $L(b^*c^*)$ \ $\{\epsilon\}$

Comment: $A$ is the language of words with **unequal** number of $b$'s and $c$'s. $L(b^*c^*)$ is the language of words that are zero or more $b$'s followed by zero or more $c$'s. The intersection of them is the words that are some number of $b$'s followed by a different number of $c$'s.

Comment: "I should not use the complement". If so, I cannot see the fact "$\{b^{n} c^{n} \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is not regular." can be useful. There are, of course, many other ways to prove $A$ is non-regular.

Comment: I'm sorry I can use the complement, I saw it 5 minutes ago.

But I have a question, can I just use the complement of $A$ and to this :
$\overline{(A))} \cap L(b^*c^*)  =  \{b^{n} c^{n} \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$

Comment: Cool, that is easier! (I was trying to include your $\epsilon$...)

Comment: Nice, thank you very much for helping me

Comment: You are welcome!